# I would like to set up a search that when user types in a city, will zoom in on the mapkit onto the city

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, search, mapkit

I would like to set up a search feature that a user can type in a search for a city and it will zoom in on the city on the mapkit. I already have a mapkit with loads of annotations and a tableview of my annotations.

I don't think i can add a search on my annotations so instead, can i just search cities and it will zoom in on cities and show the annotations in the city?

New to Xcode and any help including code examples would be much appreciated !!

Comment: Maybe not an Xcode IDE question but a question i know a lot of users are wanting to know the answer to. If you helped out rather than editing posts, maybe we can make some progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Google's Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to enable searching on a map in my apps. This API returns a bounding box for a good, appropriate zoom level for results. You can use this + `MKMapView`'s `setRegion:animated:` method to show your result(s).

Hope this helps!

Comment: mhmm am i right in saying MapKit only allows reverse Geocoding? All I want is a list of cities, not needed to be shown in a TableView because i already have a TableView of annotations, and when a user types in a City, it will zoom in on the city. I'll probably need coordinates for each city just would love some examples to get me going

Comment: Yes, Mapkit only has reverse geocoding built in, but, as donkim said, you could build a class that uses Google geocoding API to do what you are looking for.